# Does watching HD videos slow down my program using the CUDA CPU?

Tags: cuda, gpu

Everything needed is in there, but I'm classifying about 10,000 images in a ConvNet with caffe which uses the GPU. I'm watching a stream on team liquid in full screen HD, does that slow down the calculations that's going on? I'm a GPU newbie.

GPU output from `lspci | grep NVIDIA`:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF100 [GeForce GTX 480] (rev a3)
```

Comment: It's quite possible.  Benchmark it.

Comment: Yes it does, but the question is how much. HD video decoding (assuming your video player does it in GPU in the first place) isn't terribly expensive, but I guess it would be maybe somewhere around 10%? Like Robert said, benchmark it to know for sure.

Comment: sorry about duplicate, deleting. I thought I had googled throughly first.